# Property of a transient Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

An irreducible Markov chain on a countable state space $S$ is **recurrent** if one of the following equivalent statements holds:

1. There exists a finite set $A \subset S$ such that $P_x[T_A<\infty]=1$ for every $x \in A$;
2. $P_x[T_x<\infty]=1$ for every $x$ in $S$.

Here $T_A=\min\{n\geq 1:X_n \in A\}$ for any $A \subset S$. And an irreducible Markov chain is **transient** if it is not recurrent.

How can we show the following result?

> Suppose that the Markov chain $X$ is irreducible and transient. Then there exists a finite set $A \subset S$ and a point $x\in S$ such that $P_x[\tau_A<\infty]<1$, where $\tau_A=\min\{n\geq 0:X_n \in A\}$.

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: The two definitions of recurrence you've given are not, in general, equivalent (consider, for instance, the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ that always takes a step to the right, which satisfies $1$ for $A=\{x+1\}$, but not $2.$) Maybe this is just because you haven't written clearly in what sense these statements are uniform. Also, what's your question? You haven't actually written a result, because you haven't stated any assumptions. Do you want to prove that for a transient irreducible Markov chain and any finite $A\subseteq S$, there exists some $x\in S$ such that $P_x[\tau_A<\infty]<1$?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Sorry for the confusion before. I've corrected my question. Your guess is right. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: As you've written the question, recurrence means that there exists a finite $A$ such that $P_x[T_A<\infty]=1$ for every $x$ (via the first definition). The Markov chain is transient if it is not recurrent so, as you've written it, you can simply negate the above property, right?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I think the problem is that $\tau_A$ and $T_A$ have slightly different definitions.

Comment: The difference is null. $P_x[T_A=0]=1_{(x\in A)}$ by definition, so no property of the Markov chain plays into this probability. Hence, $P_x[T_A<\infty]=1$ for all $x$ if and only if $P_x[T_A<\infty]=1$ for all $x\not\in A$.

Comment: And, mind you, when you start the process at $x\not \in A$, then $T_A=\tau_A$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou If I negate the first statement of the definition, then I get that there exists a finite set $A \subset S$ and an $x \in A$ such that $P_x[T_A<\infty]<1$. But still, I have $P_x[\tau_A<\infty]=1$. How can I find an $x \in A^c$ such that $P_x[\tau_A<\infty]=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I see your worry now. It's not actually that bad, though.

So assume that your Markov Chain is transient, i.e., for any finite set $A\subseteq S$, there exists some $x\in S$ such that $P_x[T_A<\infty]<1$. All we have to argue is that there must, in particular, exist such a choice of $x\in S\setminus A$, since for such an $x$ we have $P_x[\tau_A<\infty]=P_x[T_A<\infty]$.

Indeed, assume that $P_x[T_A<\infty]=1$ for all $x\not \in A$ and let $x_0\in A$. We wish to prove that $P_{x_0}[T_A<\infty]=1$ since this would mean that the Markov Chain is, in fact, recurrent. Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ denote the Markov chain starting at $X_0=x_0$.

Now, if $X_1\in A$, then clearly $T_A<\infty$, and thus, we get that
$$
P_{x_0}(T_A=\infty)=\sum_{x\in S} 1_{x\not \in A} P_x(T_A=\infty) P_{x_0}(X_1=x)=0
$$
We conclude that $P_{x_0}(T_A<\infty)=1$.

Hence, for a given finite $A\subseteq S,$ if there exists some $x\in S$ such that $P_x[T_A<\infty]<1,$ there *must* exist some $x'\in S\setminus A$ such that $P_{x'}[T_a<\infty]<1$ and hence,
$$
P_{x'}[\tau_A<\infty]=P_{x'}[T_A<\infty]<1
$$